# Set persistent custom colors in Windows color picker

Tags: windows, colors, livecycle, livecycle-designer

Is there a way to have a custom color that has been set in the Windows color picker to be persistent? When I use Adobe LiveCycle and want to change a color to a color that I use all the time, I have to create it every time, and I figured since it's accessing the default Windows color picker, there might be a way to add the color and make it persistent.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, there is no way of doing so. Microsoft allows to redefine the default colors and it also allows for a hook to remember the user selected colors, but it has to happen in the source of the program. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646375%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#custom_template on how to set default colors when compiling a program.

Even the Microsoft default Paint program is dumb enough to forget any user defined colors.

Cheers,

p.s. For others, who are programming their own application and what to allow for saving user-defined colors: http://vbcity.com/forums/t/112635.aspx